# How to get to last child

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have 3 `<a>` tags that I want to get to the last child in IE8. Unfortunately IE8 does not support `:last-child`.

```
#breadcrumbs li:first-child div a {
  background: none !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

The top css gets to the first `<a>` but I need to try and get to the 3rd one, I tried using the below code but it doesn't work.

```
#breadcrumbs li:first-child div a + li div a + li div a {
  background: none !important;
  color: red !important;
}


<ul id="breadcrumbs">
   <li><div><a>dfgdfg</a></div></li>
   <li><div><a>fdgdfgdf</a></div></li>
   <li><div><a>fdgdfgfd</a></div></li>
   <li><div><a>dgfdgdfg</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what's your HTML? Incidentally, an `li` will *never* be the immediate sibling of an `a` element (however badly written your HTML might be).

Comment: You must include your HTML. No point of writing CSS if there's no markup

Comment: So there are always going to be 4 _li_ in _#breadcrumbs_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, somewhat, but I'd suggest:

```
#breadcrumbs li + li + li + li div a {
    /* css here */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V6apA/).

You could, of course, simply apply a class-name to either the `li` or `a` element, and then style the element(s) based on that class-name. If JavaScript is available then you could, of course, use JavaScript to add the class where necessary:

```
var list = document.getElementById('breadcrumbs'),
    aElems = list.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    lastA = aElems[aElems.length - 1];
lastA.className = 'last';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V6apA/1/).

Comment: Not an dynamic answer, is the no `last-child` css hack for IE8 ?

Comment: @S.Visser: Not with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) will bring IE8 and below up to the latest spec.  Including this should allow the use of the pseudo selectors like `:last-child`

Just include it on your page like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an nice hack to do this in combination with jQuery.

```
   /* Load this in your DOM */
   function last_child() {
      if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8) {
        $('*:last-child').addClass('last-child');
      }
    }
```

Just put in your style

```
li:last_child, li.last_child {

}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dcsH/

Comment: IE8 will still ignore the CSS rule because of the `:last-child` in the selector, so this is futile. You may as well add the class for all browsers and just select that class within the CSS instead.